# Sidekiq Job - How can I launch a job and each time change the parameter used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq

I would like to launch a job which is going to calculate the points of each user of my web-App.
Here is the problem, I would like to launch it automatically with sidekiq-scheduler.
But I have trouble to understand how I can launch my job with an argument which is going to change. I mean I have to calculate the amount of points for each user, so the argument is going to change and take different user_id.

Here is my code :

```
class PointsjoueurJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  def perform(user_id)
@user = User.find(user_id)
    @playerseason = PlayerSeason.where(user_id: @user.id)
    @forecasts = Forecast.where(player_season_id: @playerseason)
     points = []
     @forecasts.each do |forecast|
       if forecast.points_win.present? || forecast.points_lose.present?
         if forecast.points_win.present?
           points << forecast.points_win
         else forecast.points_lose.present?
           points << forecast.points_lose
         end
         @playerseason.update(number_of_points: points.sum)
       else
       end
     end
 end
```

Right now if I want to launch it, I have to go to my console then type :

```
PointsjoueurJob.perform_now(1)
```

But I want to schedule this with sidekiq-scheduler. The goal is to trigger the work everyday at 01h00 (cron: '0 1 * * *')but I don't know how to set-up the argument in order for the job to iterate trough all the users.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Make a scheduled job that iteratively calls your worker with the given parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to recalculate all users' totals, you can create a separate 'wrapper' job, which is scheduled, that in turn enqueues the individual recalculation jobs:

```rb
class RecalcPointsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    User.find_each do |u|
      PointsjoueurJob.perform_later(u.id)
    end
  end
end
```

If you are after a subset of users instead, substitute `User.where()` or `User.find_by()`.

Comment: `User.select(:id).in_batches { |batch| batch.each { |user| user.id }  }` is a safe approach.

Comment: The think is each day I'm going to add points (re-calculate the amount of points) because from a day to another, the user is probably going to earn/lose points

Comment: @gclement The idea is to have one scheduled job. This scheduled job runs every day. Every day when this job runs, it schedules and runs one new job for every `User`. So if you have 10 users, your one scheduled job runs once and queues up 10 jobs, one for each user. In this way, you are running a new job every day for every user.

Comment: Hey I finally decided to implement the solution of rmlockerd. It works fine. I scheduled it everyday and it calls all the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a Task and use `whenever`, then setup it.

on task you can write this:

```
rails g task test cron

namespace :test do
  task :cron do
    User.find_each do |u|
      PointsjoueurJob.perform_async(u.id)
    end
  end
end
```

then in `config/schedule.rb` after install `whenever`

```
every '0 1 * * *' do
  rake "test:cron"
end
```

then

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

Comment: Seems not to be a correct answer as OP is using sidekiq-scheduler and requested help getting it to work with sidekiq-scheduler. This answer is more or less a copy and paste of the accepted answer, but throws in a different gem.

Comment: Exactly I am using sidekiq scheduler, finally it works when I create a job which is calling for each user the action I want to perform.